# JPG file not showing in Android Application

Tags: android, jpeg

I have been working on a Yahtzee app that displays the dice jpg files as the dice rolled. These dice are only showing as black boxes instead of the jpg files.

I am using a Google Nexus 7 android device.

Here is an example of how I am posting the images in code.

```
mDieImageView[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.d0a);
```

d0a being the name of one of the jpgs. It is a native file.

Thanks for any help you can give.
Jake

Comment: Are you using CMYK images (i.e. convert them to PNG and check if they show up then)?

Comment: Have you tried putting your JPGs in the raw folder instead of the drawable folder?